# Linq - OfType<> not working as expected

Tags: linq, oftype

I have the following code which detects all the elements in a Silverlight application beneath a certain point

then filters them to be only those of a particular type - `CardButton`

```
IEnumerable<UIElement> elementsBeneathCursor =
                VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(new Point(xPosn, yPosn), Application.Current.RootVisual);
            IEnumerable<CardButton> cardsBeneathCursor = elementsBeneathCursor.OfType<CardButton>();
```

Even though when I inspect `elementsBeneathCursor` in the debugger, I can see there are 2 elements of type `CardButton`
Yet when I apply the `OfType<>` filter the resultant list is null

what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting list won't *actually* be null... but the sequence will be empty, if neither of those elements is actually a `CardButton`. Note that `OfType` doesn't perform any custom conversions, so if you were expecting those to happen, that may explain it.

Try going through the unfiltered list and printing out the result of calling `GetType` on each element to see what it *really* is.

Comment: ahh - I was being dumb. The source property was null in the debugger, and I needed to expand the results view to have it enumerate the results to be able to show them in the debugger